# OS X + Java + Splash image + fileDialog

Tags: java, macos, awt

Is there any way to work around this jre bug?

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8009203
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/client/jdk/rev/63bdc3543129

The FileDialog on OSX is broken if you use a splash screen. Contrary to the bug report, it is not hard to hit, esp. on OSX 10.9. You do not need to open the FileDialog immediately after launch: opening it long after launch will also invoke the bug. I've been unable to avoid it w/o removing the splash.

We can't revert to 1.6 because there are no redistributable 1.6 jres for OSX. There's still no fix in 1.8.

From the discussion, it appears it's something to do with the main thread. Perhaps there's a different way of starting the ui that would avoid this.